# How to aggregate elements of one Akka stream based on elements of another?

Tags: scala, stream, akka, reactive-programming, akka-stream

**Example scenario**: group bytes of a stream into chunks of sizes determined by another stream (of integers).

```
def partition[A, B, C](
  first:Source[A, NotUsed],
  second:Source[B, NotUsed],
  aggregate:(Int => Seq[A], B) => C
):Source[C, NotUsed] = ???

val bytes:Source[Byte, NotUsed] = ???
val sizes:Source[Int, NotUsed] = ???

val chunks:Source[ByteString, NotUsed] =
  partition(bytes, sizes, (grab, count) => ByteString(grab(count)))
```

My initial attempt includes a combination of [Flow#scan](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.2/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow@scan[T]%28zero:T%29%28f:%28T,Out%29=%3ET%29:FlowOps.this.Repr[T]) and [Flow#prefixAndTail](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.2/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow@prefixAndTail[U%3E:Out]%28n:Int%29:FlowOps.this.Repr[%28scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Out],akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[U,akka.NotUsed]%29]), but it doesn't feel quite right (see below). I also took a look at [Framing](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.2/index.html#akka.stream.javadsl.Framing$), but it doesn't seem to be applicable to the example scenario above (nor is it general enough to accommodate non-bytestring streams). I'm guessing my only option is to use [Graphs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-graphs.html) (or the more general [FlowOps#transform](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.2/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow@transform[T]%28mkStage:%28%29=%3Eakka.stream.stage.Stage[Out,T]%29:FlowOps.this.Repr[T])), but I'm not nearly proficient enough (yet) with Akka streams to attempt that.

---

Here's what I was able to come up with so far (specific to the example scenario):

```
val chunks:Source[ByteString, NotUsed] = sizes
  .scan(bytes prefixAndTail 0) {
    (grouped, count) => grouped flatMapConcat {
      case (chunk, remainder) => remainder prefixAndTail count
    }
  }
  .flatMapConcat(identity)
  .collect { case (chunk, _) if chunk.nonEmpty => ByteString(chunk:_*) }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can implement the processing as a custom `GraphStage`. The stage would have two `Inlet` elements. One taking the bytes, and the other taking the sizes. It would have one `Outlet` element producing the values.

Consider following input streams.

```
def randomChars = Iterator.continually(Random.nextPrintableChar())
def randomNumbers = Iterator.continually(math.abs(Random.nextInt() % 50))

val bytes: Source[Char, NotUsed] =
  Source.fromIterator(() => randomChars)

val sizes: Source[Int, NotUsed] =
  Source.fromIterator(() => randomNumbers).filter(_ != 0)
```

Then using information describing custom stream processing (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/stream/stream-customize.html) you can construct the `GraphStage`.

```
case class ZipFraming() extends GraphStage[FanInShape2[Int, Char, (Int, ByteString)]] {

  override def initialAttributes = Attributes.name("ZipFraming")

  override val shape: FanInShape2[Int, Char, (Int, ByteString)] =
    new FanInShape2[Int, Char, (Int, ByteString)]("ZipFraming")

  val inFrameSize: Inlet[Int] = shape.in0
  val inElements: Inlet[Char] = shape.in1

  def out: Outlet[(Int, ByteString)] = shape.out

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic =
    new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
      // we will buffer as much as 512 characters from the input
      val MaxBufferSize = 512
      // the buffer for the received chars
      var buffer = Vector.empty[Char]
      // the needed number of elements
      var needed: Int = -1
      // if the downstream is waiting
      var isDemanding = false

      override def preStart(): Unit = {
        pull(inFrameSize)
        pull(inElements)
      }

      setHandler(inElements, new InHandler {
        override def onPush(): Unit = {
          // we buffer elements as long as we can
          if (buffer.size < MaxBufferSize) {
            buffer = buffer :+ grab(inElements)
            pull(inElements)
          }
          emit()
        }
      })

      setHandler(inFrameSize, new InHandler {
        override def onPush(): Unit = {
          needed = grab(inFrameSize)
          emit()
        }
      })

      setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
        override def onPull(): Unit = {
          isDemanding = true
          emit()
        }
      })

      def emit(): Unit = {
        if (needed > 0 && buffer.length >= needed && isDemanding) {
          val (emit, reminder) = buffer.splitAt(needed)
          push(out, (needed, ByteString(emit.map(_.toByte).toArray)))
          buffer = reminder
          needed = -1
          isDemanding = false
          pull(inFrameSize)
          if (!hasBeenPulled(inElements)) pull(inElements)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And this is how you run it.

```
RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(bytes, sizes)(Keep.none) { implicit b =>
  (bs, ss) =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val zipFraming = b.add(ZipFraming())

    ss ~> zipFraming.in0
    bs ~> zipFraming.in1

    zipFraming.out ~> Sink.foreach[(Int, ByteString)](e => println((e._1, e._2.utf8String)))

    ClosedShape
}).run()
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that the `size` number of chars will *always* be picked from the *front* of `bytes`, so the elements of the resulting stream will all share the same prefix.

Comment: @Andrey you're right. I've updated my answer, with the actual implementation of a `GraphStage`, which works as a something between the Zip and Framing.